# beautifulsoup4 doesnt filter only class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get every "a" tag in an html page, and i'm trying to use
soup.find_all

here's my code:

```
r.text -- the youtube home page in html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        for lnk in soup.find_all('a' , {'class' : 'ytd-thumbnail'}):
            print(lnk)
            link = lnk.get("href")
            writeFile("queue.txt" , "https://youtube.com" + link)
            removeQueue(url)
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
<a id="thumbnail" class="yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="youtubelink">
```

but it doesn't even go into the for loop, I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Use `attrs` while passing the dictionary in the `find_all` or `find` method.

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
 for lnk in soup.find_all('a' , attrs={'class' : 'ytd-thumbnail'}):
    print(lnk)
    link = lnk.get("href")
    writeFile("queue.txt" , "https://youtube.com" + link)
    removeQueue(url)
```

Comment: can you let me know the website you are trying to scrape? Maybe some problem while sending request

Comment: I'm trying to scrape youtube, but i worked out a solution, might not be as efficient but it still works

Answer (score 0):

[You can try to use a CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). I find them cleaner and more robust. Here, `select` creates a list of all `a` tags, where the `class` attribute contains substring `ytd-thumbnail`. As a side note, I'd also suggest using the `lxml` parser for working with bs4.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for lnk in soup.select('a[class*=ytd-thumbnail]'):
    link = lnk.get("href")
    writeFile("queue.txt" , "https://youtube.com" + link)
    removeQueue(url)
```